# ¿Como instalar y usar PyQt5 en Windows?(configure.py, Error)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt5

Quiero usar el `PyQt5` en Windows, estuve buscando y encontré un archivo .zip de la página oficial de PyQt, el cual me dice como instalar el archivo ***configure.py*** en Windows, pero al ejecutar el archivo me sale el siguiente error:

> Error: Use the --qmake argument to explicitly specify a working Qt qmake.

Aquí una captura para visualizarlo mejor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este mismo archivo lo abrí con el editor PyCharm y me sale el mismo error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué puedo hacer para poder ejecutarlo bien? Mi versión de Python es la 2.7 y por lo que investigué, Python 2.7 si es compatible con PyQt5, pero no se porque me sale este error.

De antemano muchas gracias por su atención y su ayuda me vendría de mucha ayuda, valga la redundancia.

Comment: Que versión de windows usas? también puedes probar ejecutar `python configure.py --verbose` para obtener más información.

Comment: Por el momento Windows 8, ya probe con `python configure.py --verbose` pero no me aparece nada.

Comment: ¿Tienes Qt 5 instalado? ¿Alguna razón para instalar usando las fuentes y no usar pip?

Comment: Debes tener instalado qt5

Comment: Existen varias formas de instalar pyqt5, en tu caso estas tratando de compilarlo desde el código fuente, pero para ello necesitas ciertos requerimientos como por ejemplo tener instalado qt5 y sip, intuyo que esa es la razon de que genere ese error al ejecutar el comando configure.

Comment: Ok instalare el qt5 y sip @eyllanesc

Comment: Otra opción es instalar pyqt5 mediante pip, desafortunadamente solo existe para python3

Comment: Ok lo revisare gracias :)

Comment: Santiago aquí tienes todo el procedimiento: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#building-and-installing-from-source También necesitarás tener el compilador instalado (MS Visual C++). Dado que usas Python 2 y no hay soporte oficial para el, esta es la única forma. También te digo que si no tienes una razón de peso para usar Python 2 uses Python 3. Python 2 no se va a actualizar más y no tendrá soporte a partir de 2020. A falta de que las grandes distros linux den el paso a Python 3 por completo,  los paquetes importantes funcionan en Python 3 en la actualidad. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo te recomiendo que instales otra versión de Python, por lo menos la 3 y para instalar la librería de PyQt5 puedes poner este codigo en la consola de comandos: `pip install PyQt5` y con eso deberia instalarse, si quieres instalar el Designer introduces en la consola: `pip install PyQt5Designer`